# Anyone have suggestions for this riddle?

Tags: riddle

"I go up and down. I see shots each day."

The answer must be able to be found within a school environment.
Thank you!!

Comment: Not entirely sure but I have a feeling this comes from somewhere, be it a contest or other site - context or the source of the puzzle would be helpful in determining what we are meant to figure out.

Comment: Welcome to PSE! This riddle is *too broad* at the moment. If you can add more lines to it, it may narrow down to a lesser number of answers.

Comment: Seems like it must be a shot glass.  Teachers use those all the time when they're on break, right?

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is:

> A tennis ball or cricket ball

This is because:

> When a tennis ball or cricket ball is hit it is called a shot

Comment: Not every school have tennis field.

Comment: @JamalSenjaya You don't need a tennis court to have a tennis ball

Comment: So, every kind of game using ball are the answers : Football, Futsal, pingpong, badminton, volley.

Comment: This is a fine answer for a broad riddle. Welcome to PSE! Hope you already took a [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

From @Sosig answer, I think the better answer is :

> **Ball**
>  Futsal Ball, Tennis Ball, Soccer Ball, Volley Ball etc
>  You shoot the balls, the balls are go up and down, and balls are played at school.

Answer (score 0):

My guess:

> Gymnasium scoreboard

Because:

> Scores go up, while the time winds down.  Shots is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the answer is actually:

> **A basketball hoop**

"I go up and down."

> Basketball hoops can be adjusted for height.
>  They can also be raised up out of the way when not needed, or lowered into position for use.

"I see shots each day."

> Throwing the basketball at the hoop is called a "shot", so yes - a basketball hoop would see shots each day.